# F#: Connecting to Azure SQL db?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, f#

I want to connect to my Azure db and work with it from an .fsx file.

The method listed for C# is:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = "your_server.database.windows.net"; 
                builder.UserID = "your_user";            
                builder.Password = "your_password";     
                builder.InitialCatalog = "your_database";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
...
```

Is there a better way to do this in F# or should I just try to extrapolate from C# to F#? I know once the string is made we can use type providers like SqlProgrammabilityProvider.

Basically looking for an F# guide on connecting to an azure SQL server similar to this C# one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-core

Microsoft obviously producers a lot of C# content that doesn't have an F# equivalent :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this great library for database access in F#:

https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/general.html

Look specifically at the MS SQL section to connect to an MS SQL database.

Comment: Thanks that's a great guide! When I log into the Azure portal there is a much longer connection string...Is all that data necessary?

Comment: I guess some of the values you set in the connection string are optional. Maybe Azure sets the explicitly in the connection string. I would try it out with the initial connection string you have. You can always shorten it later.